# Как запускать браузер на весь экран при старте Linux?

Tags: linux, сервер, железо

Моя цель - разработать веб-интерфейс типа как в терминалах или банкоматах, который при включении устройства максимально быстро загрузится на весь экран без возможности свернуть или закрыть его. Это может быть браузер запущенный с определёнными параметрами или какая-то программа, внутри которой будет браузер.

У пользователя нет клавиатуры, только тач-скрин. Долгое нажатие не должно вызывать контекстное меню.

Comment: по поводу того из вопросов, который написан в заголовке: https://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/05/linux-distros-for-kiosks/

Comment: На счёт ARM не скажу, но вот это http://porteus-kiosk.org/index.html вполне себе шпарит на старых атомах. И с безопасностью всё ок - дистрибутив отпахал 3 приёмных кампании в ВУЗе. SSH, VNC есть.

Comment: уберите, пожалуйста, из вопроса два последних абзаца (начиная со слов «я ещё». иначе ваш вопрос является оффтопиком и подлежит закрытию. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: В общем случае - возможно. Если у браузера есть ключ, позволяющий запускать его в полноэкранном режиме или соответствующая опция в настройках.

Comment: Как вариант есть элемент в Qt QWebView пишите свою программу исполбзуя этот элемент. Решениес браузером не очень хорош т.к. если это будет на терминале, то могут возникнтуь проблемы с вылетом браузера (на пример).